# Relationship between the proportion of values in an interval around the Mean & the width of the interval in SDs

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, standard-deviation

Here’s an issue that I encountered when studying and I try to explain it with the example. Imagine a set of sample data (positive integers). *If mean=75 and Standard Deviation=10, then about 95% of data will be between 55 and 95* (i.e., mean ± 20).  Is that right? Is there a mathematical formula behind this? Should I consider things like the sample size (n) or the kind of distribution (normal or else) too?

Comment: What would it mean to "put these 6 numbers together on one equation"?

Comment: @MichaelM Indeed. Corrected.

Comment: @slightlybuilt: this is an application of the "empirical rule", see e.g. http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/empirical-rule.asp

Comment: @MichaelM nice link. so it's a rule only and only for normal distributions. thanks.

Comment: @gung edited :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule that $\approx 95\%$ of the values in a distribution lie withon $\pm 2$ SDs only holds for the normal distribution.  If you need a more general formulation hat will apply to any distribution, you need to check out [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).  This establishes that $\le 1/k^2$ values can be $>k$ SD's from the mean.

Comment: +1 Interestingly for $\pm$2 sd's it does fairly roughly hold for [continuous symmetric unimodal distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Unimodal_distributions) via Camp-Meidell. Those won't deviate more than about 6% from that 95% (between about 89%-100%; $1-\frac{4}{9k^2}$ at $k=2$ gives $8/9$ as a lower bound, which is attained by a spike-and-slab distribution). As a result a lot of more-or-less "bell shaped" distributions have in the ballpark of 95% within 2 sds. Asymmetric unimodal distributions are also often quite close (via a related bound).